# Space or newline characters breaking timeout auto message markdown

Tags: bug, chat, chat-timeout

When a chat room is placed into a temporary timeout, the one doing it can write a custom  reason. If the custom reason has markdown (e.g. italics or bold) and the last character is space or linebreak, the whole message is broken.

For example, such custom reason is fine: ([example](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5314002#5314002))

```
**no space is fine**
```

However, space breaks the whole thing, as can be seen [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/5314006#5314006):

> [image]

The raw message is:

```
**space breaks markdown **
```

And same with newline character.

Comment: I think this can be fixed in a userscript, maybe as part of SOUP?

Comment: @rene this won't be a real fix, but it might help the team to fix it faster...

Comment: Isn't that normal? **Doesn't Markdown do that everywhere? **

Comment: @Cai yes, but it doesn't normally break other things. (the timeout message should all be in italics)